# Replace element text in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following code:

```
 <xsl:if test="@class = 'abc' and name(.) = 'span'">
  <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

The template "**multiReplace**" is finding old value and replacing new values.
I want to replace the following span text with NewText text :

```
 <span class="abc">Old:</span>
```

to

```
 <span class="abc">NewText:</span>
```

but I am getting :

```
 <span class="abc">Old:NewText:</span>
```

below is the other related code:

```
    <my:params xml:space="preserve">
            <pattern>
                <old>Old: </old>
                <new>NewText:</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>Contact</old>
                <new>Phone</new>
            </pattern>
    </my:params>

    <xsl:variable name="vPats" select="document('')/*/my:params/*"/>
    <xsl:template name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
        <xsl:variable name="vPat" select="$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring($pText, 1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node()))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can you please take a look, what is the error here?

Comment: Not sure it explains your problem, but one thing that's jumping out is that you're preserving space on your patterns, and your 'Old: ' pattern has a space at the end, but the span you're expecting to replace does not.

Comment: I could not recreate this. See http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsz. (Note that I am using exlt:node-set here, because xsltransform,net does not support the use of the document function).

Comment: I think the issue may be with the code you have not shown us. Your `multiReplace` is working as expected, but something else in your XSLT is outputing the existing vale of the `span` before, or after, the replace template is called.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but the code is of more than 3000 LOC, that's why I did not put it here.

Comment: Ideally, it would help if you posted enough code to reproduce the problem. Maybe focus on the code immediately before the `<xsl:if test="@class = 'abc' and name(.) = 'span'">` statement. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Tim, Thanks for help, it got solved. and I learned a new thing from your code "xsltransform.net/bwdwsz". Thanks.